# Trimming output of expect script

Tags: expect

I am new to Expect scripts. I have Expect script written in a bash script. The script returns me the statistics I require but along with a lot of other stuff from the terminal. "**Is there any way I can get precisely the output of the command only**?"
I have spent a day searching various forums but didn't had any luck.
Any sort of help will be appreciated.

```
Stats = $(expect -c "  
spawn ssh $Username@$Host  
expect \"password:\"  
send \"$Password\r\"  
expect \"\\\\$\"  
send \"ps -A | grep java\r\"  
expect -re \"$USER.*\"  
send \"logout\"  
")
```

echo $Stats > someFile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn of logging except for the command output:

```
expect -c "
  log_user 0
    spawn ssh $Username@$Host  
    expect \"password:\"  
    send \"$Password\r\"  
    expect \"\\\\$\"  
  log_user 1
    send \"ps -A | grep java\r\"  
    expect -re \"$USER.*\"  
    send \"logout\"  
 "
```